# How to put conditions in switch statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write out a `switch` statement with conditions stored in an `array`. The conditions are whether a `score is between two numbers ('test')`. If it is between those two numbers it issues a `'response'`.

My expectation was that using the variable of `'score'` and grabbing the argument from the `array` would use my `'response'` variable to output a message about the `score` if the condition is met. I can get the outputs for `paragraph1`, however, I cannot get the output for `'response'` on `paragraph two` in my `switch statement`.

```
let section = document.querySelector('body');

let response;
let score = 85;
let test = [(score < 0 || score > 100), (score != Number || score == 0), (score > 0 || score < 19), (score > 19 || score < 39), (score > 39 || score < 69), (score > 69 || score < 89), (score > 90 || score <= 100)];
let machineActive = true;

// Add your code here


if (machineActive === false) {
    alert('Your machine is not working');
}

for (let i of test) {
    switch (score) {
        case score[0]:
            response = 'broken';
            break;
        case score[1]:
            response = 'not a number';
            break;
        case score[3]:
            response = '0-19';
            break;
        case score[4]:
            response = '19-39';
            break;
        case score[5]:
            response = '39-69';
            break;
        case score[6]:
            response = '69-89';
            break;
        case score[7]:
            response = '89-100';
            break;
        default:
            response = 'If this is showing it is the default and not working';
    }
}


// Don't edit the code below here!

section.innerHTML = ' ';
let para1 = document.createElement('p');
let para2 = document.createElement('p');

para1.textContent = `Your score is ${ score }`;
para2.textContent = response;

section.appendChild(para1);
section.appendChild(para2);
```

Comment: Rather than checking the score[index] in the switch case you can write the condition in switch like , case score < 0 || score > 100 :

Comment: This is an assignment from the mozilla website on the 'test your skills' section. It asked me to make a switch statement for those conditions rather than using the else, else if, else. 

It is conditionals 3:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Test_your_skills:_Conditionals

Comment: // Rather than checking the score[index] in the switch case you can write the condition in switch //     

I did try to do that, but it still will not read the conditions. Instead of the array I originally had '(score > 0 || score < 19)' in each case instead of the '[0]' from the array.

Comment: you are attempting to create a complicated solution to a simple problem. instead of creating a bunch of scenarios, turning them into an array, and then looping through the array, just create if/then statements for the conditions. what is the value of creating an array in the middle of your logic?

Comment: This is an assignment from the mozilla website that asked me to use a switch statement with these conditions. The assignment prior to that I did create if/then statements and it worked fine. =)

Answer (score 3):

To write switch cases with range, you'll need to write something like below (showing case 1 and 3 as example below):

```
switch (true) {
    case ((score < 0 || score > 100)):
        -- Execute case 1 ---
        break;
    case ((score > 0 || score < 19)):
        -- Execute case 3 ---
        break;
    default:
        -- Execute default case ---
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: I wrote this answer before seeing in the comments that using a `switch` statement was a requirement for a JS challenge. But I'll leave it here anyway

`switch` is not really appropriate for what you are trying to do. Here is how I would do it:

```js
const section = document.querySelector('body');

const score = 85;
const conditions = [
 { test: s => isNaN(s),           response: 'not a number' },
 { test: s => (s < 0 || s > 100), response: 'broken'       },
 { test: s => s < 19,             response: '0-18'         },
 { test: s => s < 39,             response: '19-38'        },
 { test: s => s < 69,             response: '39-68'        },
 { test: s => s < 89,             response: '69-88'        },
 { test: s => true,               response: '89-100'       }
];

const response = conditions.find(cond => cond.test(score)).response;

// Don't edit the code below here!

section.innerHTML = ' ';
let para1 = document.createElement('p');
let para2 = document.createElement('p');

para1.textContent = `Your score is ${ score }`;
para2.textContent = response;

section.appendChild(para1);
section.appendChild(para2);
```

Comment: what does the 'cond' in the cond.test refer to?

Comment: @coe `conditions.find()` will execute a function you provide it for each element in the `conditions` Array, one by one, until it finds one that returns `true`. So here, `cond` is one of the `conditions`. And `cond.test` refers to the `test` property of that condition. You could rename `cond` to anything you want, though. `x => x.test(score)` would also work

Comment: wow that is brilliant, I will put that in my toolbox, thank you!

Comment: Glad you like it :) If you don't know these already, I recommend you to learn about `map`, `find`, `filter`, `reduce`. I was mind-blown when I discovered these (especially `reduce`). They can be really helpful in a lot of situations, and, sometimes, can make your code cleaner and easier to read

Answer (score 0):

there's no point in turning these conditions into an array. you are over-complicating things. just do this:

```
if(score < 0 || score > 100) {
  return 'broken';
} else if (score != Number || score == 0) {
  return 'not a number'
} else if (score > 19 || score < 39){
  return '20-38'
}
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you for the solution and it works. The assignment before this I did exactly what you said. However, on the mozilla website it asked me to take what you are doing and turn it into a switch statement instead.